# How do I get KTOR Logging to compile on Android?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I don't know what "implementation" to put in my build.gradle file, nor what "import" to use in my source code to make it so the symbol "Logging" is recognized. Please help. NONE of the examples on the Internet show how to do this part.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
```

kotlin file:

```
import io.ktor.client.features.logging.*
```

Check out more in the [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/client-logging.html)

Comment: The documentation method didn't work on my PC.

Comment: @Bungles I've double checked and it's a valid link, maybe you have problems with your internet, try using VPN or [google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9KBDfFAS8KoJ:https://ktor.io/docs/client-logging.html)